# How do I convert to EPSG:3857 with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, epsg

I have some TIFs in EPSG4326 the GeoTiff info looks like:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

How do convert them into EPSG:3857 so that the GeoTiff info reads something like:

```
PROJCS["Google Maps Global Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

Comment: `gdal_translate -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 input.tif output.tif`

Comment: Sorry, of course gdalwarp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) utility.

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: Hi, just found this from Google. Any idea why the above command gives me the following errors?

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed: EPSG:3857

Comment: @Z.Reticulan your environment is not set correctly. Search for that error (Google, StackExchange), there's plenty of answers.

Comment: Thanks. I followed Alfonso's instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764046/gdal-ogr2ogr-cannot-find-proj-db-error

Answer (score 1):

Use EPSG:3857. That is the official EPSG code number for Google mercator projection.

900913 was incorporated in GDAL some time ago, but is now dropped in favour of 3857.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I do the actual conversion to EPSG:3857

Comment: See the answer by Luke for the command line syntax.